# Bazel & protobuf: how to choose a specific protoc version

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

I am working in a project using some proto sources that are already compiled using a specific version, I also need to compile some custom protos that are cohabiting in the same project, so the protoc needs to match the one that was used to generate the other ones.

I can see in the pre-generated ones:

```cpp
#if PROTOBUF_VERSION < 3009000
#if 3009002 < PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION
```

In mines:

```cpp
#if PROTOBUF_VERSION < 3017000
#if 3017000 < PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION
```

I don't quite understand which protoc is being used, the one installed on my system is 3.19.4.

Also this is my WORKSPACE:

```
http_archive(
    name = "rules_proto",
    sha256 = "66bfdf8782796239d3875d37e7de19b1d94301e8972b3cbd2446b332429b4df1",
    strip_prefix = "rules_proto-4.0.0",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/refs/tags/4.0.0.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/refs/tags/4.0.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)
load("@rules_proto//proto:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_dependencies", "rules_proto_toolchains")
rules_proto_dependencies()
rules_proto_toolchains()

http_archive(
    name = "com_github_grpc_grpc",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/grpc/grpc/archive/refs/tags/v1.44.0.tar.gz",
    ],
    sha256 = "8c05641b9f91cbc92f51cc4a5b3a226788d7a63f20af4ca7aaca50d92cc94a0d",
    strip_prefix = "grpc-1.44.0",
)
load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_deps.bzl", "grpc_deps")
grpc_deps()
load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_extra_deps.bzl", "grpc_extra_deps")
grpc_extra_deps()
```

The error I am currently getting is:

```
In file included from cc/tensorflow/plugin_primeclient/grappler/grappler.cc:7:
bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/cc/tensorflow/plugin/protos/graph.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
   12 | #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
      |  ^~~~~
bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/cc/tensorflow/plugin/protos/graph.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
   13 | #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
      |  ^~~~~
bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/cc/tensorflow/plugin/protos/graph.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
   14 | #error your headers.
      |  ^~~~~
```

Comment: So you have some generated headers that are checked in/vendored and some that are generated?

Comment: Yes, you're correct

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and describe the general process I take when tracking dependency problems down in Bazel, as it seems to be a regular problem that you'll probably run into again.

Before Bazel does anything to do with the build it's going to look in your WORKSPACE file to see if it needs to fetch any dependencies. It might not seem like an important detail, but Bazel handles WORKSPACE dependencies from top to bottom. We can use this behaviour to override the protobuf version used. Checkout the [maybe macro](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/utils#maybe) if your interested in how this works.

So in your WORKSPACE file, the first dependency that you have is 'rules_proto' @ version 4.0.0 with the http_archive. Then you are loading two macros from 'rules_proto' here;

```py
load("@rules_proto//proto:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_dependencies", "rules_proto_toolchains")
rules_proto_dependencies()
rules_proto_toolchains()
```

So first things first let's head over to the [rules_proto releases page](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/releases/tag/4.0.0) and find your specific release. Then click on the little hash on that page (circled in red).
[image: bazel 4.0 release hash]

Then click "browse files" in the top right;
[image]

This will allow you to browse the state of that repository at that specific version. Now as you loaded "repositories.bzl" you'll want to open that up and inspect it (ctrl-F search for protobuf). You'll find that it calls another [private macro](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/blob/fcad4680fee127dbd8344e6a961a28eef5820ef4/proto/repositories.bzl#L32) i.e.

```py
protobuf_workspace(name = "com_google_protobuf")
```

If we look for where that [macro was loaded](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/blob/fcad4680fee127dbd8344e6a961a28eef5820ef4/proto/repositories.bzl#L20) you'll see that you'll need to follow that through to the 'proto/private/dependencies.bzl';

```py
load("//proto/private:dependencies.bzl", "dependencies", "maven_dependencies", "protobuf_workspace")
```

After opening that up and searching again for protobuf you'll find [the line that specifies the protobuf version](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/blob/fcad4680fee127dbd8344e6a961a28eef5820ef4/proto/private/dependencies.bzl#L25);

```py
    "com_github_protocolbuffers_protobuf": {
        #...
    },
```

So by the looks of it you are using an older version of protobuf with Bazel than what is installed on your system. So in order to override the protobuf version in Bazel you need to simply add it as a dependency in your WORKSPACE **before** the rules_proto repository. e.g.

```py
# file: //:WORKSPACE
http_archive(
    name = "com_github_protocolbuffers_protobuf",
    # TODO: Leave this empty and Bazel will tell you what to put here when you build.
    sha256 = "",
    # Note: Same version as your system deps.
    strip_prefix  = "protobuf-3.19.4",
    urls = [
# Note: Same version as your system deps.
"https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.19.4/protobuf-all-3.19.4.tar.gz"
     ],
)

http_archive(
    name = "rules_proto",
# The rest of the WORKSPACE...
```

Comment: Thank you that is an awesome explanation! What I am failing to understand is why there is a mismatch in versions... If bazel the issue comes from bazel using my local protobuf lib, then how come it ended up generating protos not using my local protoc?
Also I found that my 'local' protoc is 3.6.1 in fact (I am using remote container and check the correct one), this seems a bit too low....

Comment: Your problem is you are mixing versions. Bazel doesn't use the system installed protoc. It downloads the source code for protoc at a specific version and builds it from source. When you are using your system installed version you will very likely be using a different version to what bazel uses in its sandboxed build.

Comment: I am not using my system installed version, I was importing files from tensorflow which have been generated  by protobuf, I don't need these files in fact so I removed the import but the issue remain.
So I have absolutely no clue how can bazel compile protos for me and then complain about the proto compiler used... Maybe it's the grpc import, but at the same time I placed the rules_proto before so it should override the protobuf version.

Comment: Have you tried to just copying over the contents of the tensorflow WORKSPACE file? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/WORKSPACE

Comment: You'd need to change all the `@//` to `@org_tensorflow//` but other than that you should have a near identical environment.

Comment: The thing is I am not compiling against tensorflow sources, I am using some of the headers as I am working on a tensorflow plugin.
The structure of my project is a bazel package which consist of a grpc client and another package which is the tensorflow plugin. The tensorflow plugin uses protocol buffers to compile some of the tensorflow protos.
I think the source of conflict is the grpc from the client and the protocol buffer/rules proto needed by the plugin.
The grpc protos in the client compile without and this is adding up to the confusion.